# Python 3.5 Cannot set Firefox profile using selenium webdriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox, webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import FirefoxProfile

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX

caps["marionette"] = True

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "False")
profile.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir", "C:a directory")
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

mydriver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, firefox_profile=profile)
```

See my code above. When webdriver opens a firefox browser instance it does not adhere to the profile I am trying to set and it ignores the settings and defaults to firefoxes default. Any idea what I am missing?